# Images process real time ant get maximum usage colors from any images like Apple iTunes in Update available applications background color

Tags: php

Images process real time ant get maximum usage colors from any images like Apple iTunes in Update available applications **image background color** of any type of image .PNG, .JPEG .GIF etc

In Apple iTunes desktop application - Whenever click on any update available application then show like images below

[image]

i want to implement like this in web application, i have also observe google images is also not doing like this but i want it same as iTunes App

[image]

want **answer in sample code** not tutorials, i was read many image processing library in PHP but not getting.

Comment: Great that you "want answer in sample code". Do we also have to setup the server you want? Are we to create the pictures too? When do we have to be finished?

Comment: yes, server related no any issue, i just want solution.... i have decided and make it one wonderful web site....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Source Link](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5577-PHP-Get-the-most-used-colors-in-an-image.html) This class can be used to get the most used colors in an image. you can implement on your way and your needs... its my try to get you best results.....

It can open an image file in JPEG format and traverse its pixels to find which are the most used colors. It can skip a given number of analyzed pixels according to the granularity parameter.

The class returns an array of top most used colors up to a given limit of number or colors. The colors are returned in RGB hexadecimal format.

```
function getImageColor($imageFile_URL, $numColors, $image_granularity = 5) 
    { 
           $image_granularity = max(1, abs((int)$image_granularity)); 
           $colors = array(); 
           //find image size 
           $size = @getimagesize($imageFile_URL); 
           if($size === false) 
           { 
              user_error("Unable to get image size data"); 
              return false; 
           } 
           // open image 
           $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($imageFile_URL); 
           if(!$img) 
           { 
                 user_error("Unable to open image file"); 
              return false; 
           } 

           // fetch color in RGB format 
           for($x = 0; $x < $size[0]; $x += $image_granularity) 
           { 
              for($y = 0; $y < $size[1]; $y += $image_granularity) 
              { 
                 $thisColor = imagecolorat($img, $x, $y); 
                 $rgb = imagecolorsforindex($img, $thisColor); 
                $red = round(round(($rgb['red'] / 0x33)) * 0x33); 
                 $green = round(round(($rgb['green'] / 0x33)) * 0x33); 
                 $blue = round(round(($rgb['blue'] / 0x33)) * 0x33); 
                 $thisRGB = sprintf('%02X%02X%02X', $red, $green, $blue); 
                 if(array_key_exists($thisRGB, $colors)) 
                 { 
                        $colors[$thisRGB]++; 
                 } 
                 else 
                 { 
                        $colors[$thisRGB] = 1; 
                 } 
              } 
           } 
           arsort($colors); 
           // returns maximum used color of image format like #C0C0C0. 
           return array_slice(array_keys($colors), 0, $numColors); 
    }
```

For RGB Colors

```
// html color to convert in RGB format color like R(255) G(255) B(255)   
    function getHtml2Rgb($str_color) 
    { 
        if ($str_color[0] == '#') 
            $str_color = substr($str_color, 1); 

            if (strlen($str_color) == 6) 
            list($r, $g, $b) = array($str_color[0].$str_color[1], 
                                 $str_color[2].$str_color[3], 
                                 $str_color[4].$str_color[5]); 
        elseif (strlen($str_color) == 3) 
            list($r, $g, $b) = array($str_color[0].$str_color[0], $str_color[1].$str_color[1], $str_color[2].$str_color[2]); 
        else 
            return false; 

        $r = hexdec($r); $g = hexdec($g); $b = hexdec($b); 
        $arr_rgb = array($r, $g, $b); 
        // Return colors format liek R(255) G(255) B(255)   
        return $arr_rgb; 
    }
```

[Source Code Link](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/27950.html)

Sample output

[image: sample results looks like this]

Comment: i have download source and just check sample .jpeg image and getting 10 most used colors.... i am not believe its in PHP. thanks a lot....